# xcolor-material issue with cmyk document

Tags: color

I am working in a cmyk document with package xcolor-material, the issue is a color definitions produce bad color results. For example:
the desire color is the left and the exit is the right.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xcolor-material}
\usepackage{sectsty}

\sectionfont{\LARGE\normalfont\sffamily\color{MaterialGreen500}}

\begin{document}

\colorsample[HTML]{MaterialGreen500}
\colorsample[cmyk]{MaterialGreen500}

\colorsample[HTML]{MaterialRed500}
\colorsample[cmyk]{MaterialRed500}


\section{Example}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you show us a MWE?

Comment: where did you get the numbers from? the cmyk values are not as I'd expect eg for the second one  this convertor gives different 0,.73,.78,.04  http://www.colorhexa.com/f44336

Comment: @DavidCarlisle My guess would be the conversion if from `xcolour`: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\convertcolorspec{HTML}{4CAF50}{cmyk}\tmp 
\definecolor{MaterialGreen}{cmyk}{\tmp} 
\tmp
\end{document}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the colour conversion algorithm of gimp (using the profile "Generic CMYK") instead of the one from `xcolor`.

Not exactly the same colour, but closer:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xcolor-material}

\definecolor{mygreen}{cmyk}{0.69,0.01,0.82,0.01}
\definecolor{myred}{cmyk}{0.,0.81,0.75,0.}

\begin{document}
\colorsample[cmyk]{mygreen}
\colorsample[HTML]{MaterialGreen500}
\colorsample[cmyk]{MaterialGreen500}

\colorsample[cmyk]{myred}
\colorsample[HTML]{MaterialRed500}
\colorsample[cmyk]{MaterialRed500}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank, I assuming what is prefer redefine my proper style